# How to avoid content similar to titles appearing at the bottom of the page, hoping to automatically breakpage and appear on the second page

Tags: sectioning

Let me first describe the effect I want. For the `\section` command, when there is text after it. The content in the `\section` will not appear at the bottom of the page. Below is an example code to demonstrate this effect.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\par
xxx\par
\section{zzzz}
xxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\par
xxx\par
\section{zzzz}
% xxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to know how this is achieved. I want to customize a command that only achieves this effect. How to modify the definition of the  `\aaa` command to have the above effect.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{\vspace{15pt}\textbf{#1}\vspace{15pt}\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\par
xxx\par
% \section{zzzz}
\aaa{zzzz}
xxxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a penalty between the section and the text after it that prevents a page break. As both don't fit in the page both wanders to the next. It is not quite clear what your use case it. Your second case would normally only happen if the section is the last thing in the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have added a example, i.e., `\aaa`. I understand that it may be related to penalty, but I am a bit confused about how to use it specifically. It would be great if you could provide an example that can directly take effect in the above code. Thank you.

Comment: You might also look at the `needspace` package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your prompt. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\section prevents the break with the help of a `\nobreak` before the `\vspace` (which should be after the `\par`). Additionally it adds `\@afterheading`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\aaa}[1]{\vspace{15pt}\textbf{#1}\par\nobreak\vspace{15pt}\@afterheading}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-6]
\par
xxx\par
% \section{zzzz}
\aaa{zzzz}
xxxx
\end{document}
```